# How to create .bat file for rest assured project?

Tags: batch-file, testng, rest-assured

I am working on a Rest-Assured project which consists of testng.xml file also. I am trying to run the testng.xml file through batch. But it gives me error as -

> could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

Below is the code for the batch file :-

```
cd C:\Users\workspace\RestAssured
set projectPath=C:\Users\workspace\RestAssured
java org.testng.TestNG "%projectPath%\testng.xml"
pause
```

I went through numerous batch file creation solution but still I am not able to replicate it. And also, in some solutions I see they have added classpath also like - `set classpath=C:\Users\workspace\RestAssured\bin`. But this bin folder doesn't exist in my project.

And also, Let's say, I have my project at C drive location. How to take the path of the project dynamically for different users?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you set the class path properly.

Here's what you need to do:

1. Download the latest version of TestNG `7.0.0` from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/testng/testng/7.0.0/).
2. Download the dependencies that TestNG and have them made available in a folder (say lib). The easiest way of figuring out the actual download URLs is by doing 
   `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" + groupId + "/ + artifactId + "/" + version` (replace all `.` with `/`)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.beust</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcommander</artifactId>
    <version>1.72</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
    <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.21</version>
</dependency>
```

3. Once you have everything in your lib folder, create a batch file wherein you set the classpath to refer to all the jars in the lib folder,

   cd C:\Users\workspace\RestAssured
   set projectPath=%cd%
   java -classpath "lib/*" org.testng.TestNG "%projectPath%\testng.xml"
   pause

This should take care of all of your questions.

Comment: I tried the above approach. But still I can see this result - ...
... TestNG 7.0.0-7 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...


===============================================
    Test
    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Suite
Total tests run: 0, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

Comment: This is my tstng.xml - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" verbose="2">
  <test thread-count="5" name="Test">
     <classes>
      <class name="com.code.impCode.TC_004_getData"/>
    </classes> 
    
     <!-- <packages>
            <package name="com.staples.acctsrvc.v1.masterAccountController"/>
    </packages>   -->
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->